# PHP: Remove the first and last item of the array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have this array:

```
 $array = array('10', '20', '30.30', '40', '50');
```

**Questions:**

What is the fastest/easiest way to remove the first item from the above array?
What is the fastest/easiest way to remove the last item from the above array?

So the resulting array contains only these values:

- '20'
- '30.30'
- '40'

Comment: why to you need "fastest" whay? how many items in your array?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Consider a situation where there are more items in the array, he has just given a sample i think.

Comment: I refuse to consider such a nonsense. Large data arrays is database concern.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: You are right but you would see a host of such questions where no optimization is needed but people especially new comers still ask for that.

Comment: So, they to be educated of dangers of premature optimization.

Comment: No, they to be educated about both. to OP: "Premature optimization is bad!" Okay that's out of the way. Now, on to answering the question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Using array_slice is simplest

```
$newarray = array_slice($array, 1, -1);
```

If the input array has less than 3 elements in it, the output array will be empty.

Comment: You've marked this as the correct answer, but if I were you I'd actually check to see if it truly is. This command necessitates copying a large section of memory. Using `array_{shift,pop}` will avoid copying that memory. Write a script where you instantiate a really large array and then call your function until the array has 0 (or 1) elements.

Comment: I benchmarked `array_shift` and `array_pop` solution vs `array_slice` solution. Using `array_slice` is very slower than the other one.

Answer (score 71):

To remove the first element, use [array_shift](http://php.net/array_shift), to remove last element, use [array_pop](http://php.net/array_pop):

```
<?php    
$array = array('10', '20', '30.30', '40', '50');
array_shift($array);
array_pop($array);
```

Comment: I think your answer is the right one. It has better performance than `array_slice`.

Answer (score 11):

```
array_pop($array); // remove the last element
array_shift($array); // remove the first element
```

Answer (score 7):

[array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is going to be the fastest since it's a single function call.

You use it like this:
`array_slice($input, 1, -1);`

Make sure that the array has at least 2 items in it before doing this, though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use -1 instead of count($input)-2 ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that at first. Fixed.

Comment: array_slice needs to create a new array, which means its way way way slower than array_pop

Comment: If the array has less than 2 items, `array_slice`  will work.

Answer (score 6):

Check this code:

```
$arry = array('10', '20', '30.30', '40', '50');
$fruit = array_shift($arry);
$fruit = array_pop($arry);
print_r($arry);
```

Answer (score 5):

Removes the first element from the array, and returns it:

```
array_shift($array);
```

Removes the last element from the array, and returns it:

```
array_pop($array);
```

If you dont mind doing them both at the same time, you can use:

```
array_shift($array,1,-1));
```

to knock off the first and last element at the same time.

Check the [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), [array_pop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) documentation :)

Comment: `array_shift` does not accept 3 parameters. It has only one parameter. array_shift($array, 1, -1) is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array  = array("khan","jan","ban","man","le");
$sizeof_array = sizeof($array);
$last_itme = $sizeof_array-1;
//$slicearray= array_slice($array,'-'.$sizeof_array,4);// THIS WILL REMOVE LAST ITME OF ARRAY
$slicearray = array_slice($array,'-'.$last_itme);//THIS WILL REMOVE FIRST ITEM OF ARRAY
foreach($slicearray as $key=>$value)
{
  echo $value;  
  echo "<br>";
}   
?>
```

Comment: `array_slice` will create a new array, so it is very slow. This answer is using it twice!!