# how to retrieve element between the first and the last elments in multi array

Tags: php, php-5.3

i have two arrays...multi arrays
**the first called location and into it (cities names)
 i want to get the element name but not the first or the last
how to do that

```
location":Array (
 [0] => stdClass Object ([code] => BKK [name] => Bangkok )
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [code] => SIN [name] => Singapore Changi )
 [2] => stdClass Object ( [code] => KUL [name] => Kuala Lumpur ) )
```

**my code not work**

```
<?php

        foreach ($obj->location as $lo):
            if (!reset(reset($lo)) and !end(end($lo))) {
                echo $lo->name . ',';
            }
        endforeach;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**array_slice()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$array = array_slice($obj->location, 1, -1, true); // to preserve the keys
```

Example: http://codepad.org/Hi4yCTXE

Also, you can use [array_shift()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first element, and [array_pop()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to remove the last. In this way, you'll remain with an array without those elements, and with the index reset

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way may be the following:

```
$counter = 0;
$last = count($obj->location - 1);

foreach($obj->location as $lo) {
    if($counter && $counter != $last) echo $lo->name;
    $counter++;
}
```

Though this assumes your array is built in an order that places the first and last items truly first and last.  If not, you may need to sort your array ahead of time.  In PHP, what determines the first and last element in an array is the order in which it is assigned, not necessarily the key.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first and last element of your array with array_slice and then use a foreach loop to print what you want.

```
$newloc = array_slice($obj->location, 1, -1);

foreach($newloc as $loc)
{
    echo $loc->name;
}
```

See [PHP: Remove the first and last item of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675257/php-remove-the-first-and-last-item-of-the-array)

Sidenote : if you're doing this on a very large array, it would be better to use array_shift and array_pop.